# How can I initiate transform operations through python?

Tags: python, interface, 3d-view

I'm trying to figure out how I can initiate transform operations like grab, scale and rotate. I don't want to execute the transform, just activate it so you can use your mouse and keyboard to perform the operation and accept.

Let me give you some context. I'm working on making a open hardware project to create a 3D mouse with arduino for blender. So far I am able to communicate between the board and blender by the use of python and a serial connection. I managed to find enough info to control the viewport with python so I can use a a joystick in conjunction with a rotary encoder to move around the modal. I would also love to add buttons that allows the user to customize its function to activate common tasks like scale, grab and zoom. Select all is an easy one but those 3 I'm having a hard time figuring out how to start the transform so the user can continue it. Even if I can't initiate the transform, is there a way I can fake a keyboard event though python in blender to make it think the user pressed G for grab?

Thanks, any help will be greatly appropriated.

Comment: you can simply call the appropriate operator like `bpy.ops.transform.translate('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` , faking keyboard events is more of python question see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13564851/generate-keyboard-events)